# Production mode: Does minificator in React changes names of component's functions?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

In my React project i want to render some component with some props, which passed from an object (this object hasn't the 'name' key!!!).
In this component I have the render-condition, in which I compare what component passed in props.
In condition I linked to name of the component's function because I don't want to import the Component_1 to the ParentComponent.
Here is my code:

I've tried to rewrite render-condition and fixed my bug!

```
//code with bug in production-mode
import React from 'react';
export default class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
   const component = this.props.component;

   return (
    {component.name === 'Component_1' ? Component_1 : Component_2}
);
}

//code without bug in production-mode
import React from 'react';
import Component_1 from 'components/component1';

export default class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
   const component = this.props.component;

   return (
    {component === Component_1 ? Component_1 : Component_2}
);
}
```

Problem: in development mode it renders without bugs, but in production mode I have bug in condition - component.name not equal 'Component_1' (for example: it is equal 't').
My idea - that's because in production bundle functions names are minified and React can't verify the condition.
Do you have any other ideas why I can't refer to function's name?

Comment: On minification function names are changed, I guess you have to achieve it in a different way. If you could expand on what you are trying to solve it might be easier to help you out.

Comment: I'd want to know only changes minificator names if functions or not. And I solved my problem in //code without bug in production-mode. May be you know how to solve it without importing component?

Answer (score 1):

In production mode, don't compare the name with plain string. Instead, you can try this

```
return (
    {component.name === Component_1.name ? Component_1 : Component_2}
);
```

And because you returning `Component_1` and `Component_2`, I guess you'll have to import both of the components either way.